# Data is not storing to Firebase Realtime Databse - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

//Please Help :

What i want to do:

I want to upload video to firebase from app and create realtime database child which store the uploded video link and some more information.

What error is coming:
Video is successfully uploading but Databse child is not creating in Realtime Database.

Please help me to fix my problem.

Here is my codes :-
AddReel.java

```
public class AddReel extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView cancel,pick_image;
Button reel;
Button browse,upload;
MediaController mediaController;
EditText vtitle;
VideoView videoView;
EditText description;
CardView reel_card;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//    profileUrl,username,memer
String reel_url;
Uri videouri;

FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference userRef,reelRef;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
StorageReference storageReference;

private long counterReel=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reel);


    init();

    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user=auth.getCurrentUser();
    vtitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vtitle);
    storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Reels");
    userRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    reelRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reels");



    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddReel.this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
    }

//        getData();

    browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadReel();
        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (data !=null)
        {
            videouri=data.getData();
            videoView.setVideoURI(videouri);

        }

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void uploadReel()
{
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(AddReel.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("New Post");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    if (videouri == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Meme select!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    {
        final StorageReference sRef=storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+getExtension(videouri));
        sRef.putFile(videouri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                sRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        reel_url=uri.toString();
                        //database

//  SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("post",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
//                            editor.putString("id",postid);
//                            editor.apply();

                        saveReelsDataInFirebase(reel_url);



                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddReel.this, "Error"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                double progress=(100*snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+((int)progress) +"%...");


            }
        });
    }
}

private void init()
{
    videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    upload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
    browse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.browse);
    mediaController=new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();

}

public String getExtension(Uri videouri)
{
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return  mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(getContentResolver().getType(this.videouri));
}


private void saveReelsDataInFirebase(final String postReel)
{
    reelRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                counterReel=snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            }else
            {
                counterReel=0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


    userRef.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists())
            {
                String n=snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                String m=snapshot.child("memer").getValue().toString();
                String p=snapshot.child("profileUrl").getValue().toString();

                Date date=new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm a");
                String currentDate=format.format(date);

                String reelid=reelRef.push().getKey();
                HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("date",currentDate);
                map.put("reelid",reelid);
                map.put("title",vtitle);
                map.put("postReel",postReel);
                map.put("publisher",user.getUid());
                map.put("profile",p);
                map.put("memer",m);
                map.put("username",n);
                map.put("counterPost",counterReel);
                

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(AddReel.this, "New post added!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(AddReel.this,HomeActivity.class));


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Model class:-

Filemodel.java

```
public class Filemodel {

private String date;
private String reelid;
private String title;
private String postReel;
private  String publisher;
private String profile;
private  String memer;
private  String username;
private long counterReel;

public Filemodel(String date, String reelid, String title, String postReel, String publisher, String profile, String memer, String username, long counterReels) {
    this.date = date;
    this.reelid = reelid;
    this.title = title;
    this.postReel = postReel;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.profile = profile;
    this.memer = memer;
    this.username = username;
    this.counterReel = counterReels;
}

public Filemodel()
{

}


public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getreelid() {
    return reelid;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getpostReel() {
    return postReel;
}

public void setpostreel(String postreel) {
    this.postReel = postreel;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public String getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public String getMemer() {
    return memer;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public long getCounterPost() {
    return counterReel;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step should be to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
    throw databaseError.toException(); 
}
```

Aside from that, I don't see any call to `setValue` or `updateChildren` in the code you shared, which are the only calls that write data to the database. So you might want to have a look at the documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data).